# Android Studio GIT error when trying to annotate

Tags: android, git

When I right click on the side and click "Annotate" I get the following error

> Error:Failed to annotate: com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException:
>   fatal: no such path app/src/main/java/.. ../MainActivity.java in HEAD 
>   during executing git -c core.quotepath=false blame --porcelain -l -t
>   -w HEAD -- app/src/main/java/.. ../MainActivity.java

Google didnt help.  I tried cloning the repo again but didnt work. I have no idea whats going on.

Also when I try to look at the history, the console says something like

> fatal: no such path .../MainActivity.java in HEAD

Comment: What does happen if you run the same `git` command in a terminal?

Comment: not sure how to do that in command line

Comment: Try to run `git -c core.quotepath=false blame --porcelain -l -t -w HEAD -- app/src/main/java/.. ../MainActivity.java ` in your working copy directory in your terminal. Maybe it will reveal something.

Comment: wow fuck. i got it.  it was because i renamed my package by just changing the case and git didnt recognize it.  so it thinks those files dont exist.  I changed it back and it works now

Comment: It would work if you'd rename it with `git mv` or AS since I think you have configured AS/Git integration well. Just curious: which way exactly have you renamed the file so AS didn't execute `git mv` itself?

Answer (score 6):

I struggled for months with this happening but just for Git submodule code - and in my case the "Oh you renamed your folders" solutions didn't help me at all.

Finally this was the solution for my case:

1. Go to Android Studio Preferences, `Version Control` tab
2. Under the Directory list, add in all the submodule root folders (you may find they are already there but under an "Unregistered" header in the list - in that case you can simply select those and hit the + button, bottom left, to add them.)

That's it, fixed my annotate and git change highlighting issues.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It was under "Directory mappings", and the submodule path was there but as an "Unregistered root". When I selected it and added it with a +, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The OP got it resolved now, but I am answering this for who came across this problem like I just did.

The paths in git repo are case-sensitive. So try to **rename your folder in git to match the checkout folder on your system**, especially if you are on Mac/Linux. Try run annotate again should work now.

```
git mv FOO foo2
git mv foo2 foo
git commit -m "Fix case sensitivity"
```